# Python wordsearch generator overlaps words

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have been trying to make a word search grid generator but I've got one problem with this code and I don't know how to solve it. This code generates the word search grid and puts the words from the list in it but sometimes some characters of that word get overwritten by another word (as the position assignment is random and doesn't consider the previously generated indices). I want to fix this but I don't know how...

```
import string
import random

height = 15
width = 15
def wordsearch(word,grid):
    word = random.choice([word])
    wordlength = len(word)

    direction = random.choice([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
    xsize = width   if direction[0] == 0 else width  - wordlength
    ysize = height if direction[1] == 0 else height - wordlength

    x = random.randrange(0,xsize)
    y = random.randrange(0,ysize)

    print([x,y])

    for i in range(0,wordlength):
        grid[y + direction[1]*i][x + direction[0]*i] = word[i]
    return grid

grid = [[random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(0,width)] for j in range(0,height)]

for word in ['hello','red','yellow','green','blue','father','mother','sister','brother','food','drinks', 'cheese']:
    grid = wordsearch(word, grid)

print("\n".join(map(lambda row: " ".join(row), grid)))
```

For example at [1,0] it generates 'green' downwards but the first 'e' got replaced by the word 'blue' generated at [1,2].

```
[6, 1]
[12, 7]
[2, 4]
[1, 0]
[1, 2]
[7, 2]
[7, 4]
[11, 6]
[3, 9]
[7, 10]
[5, 0]
[6, 0]
t g n v x d c f y r s m d z o
t r f v j h r h l l o r e v e
y b y v w t w i e y v f r r m
z e l b w c e a n e y z c w j
a n y u l l o m z k s h u z d
u s i c e i z h o a s e c j r
l c g n v y k e c t b s g q g
e f b c p s f r x e h i r t f
y q p r t h h a z e o s e z h
o l x b r o t h e r e t r z x
m f m m n u o f j d s e i e e
v z u d k x t k o v i r d o k
l s q o q w a l o o u n y y v
m q c u r v w i f d d d a p g
b a h c f o y g g n x e v z s
```

Comment: You have nothing in place to prevent that. In fact, as you haven't stored anywhere which spaces were chosen for previous words, you have no *way* to prevent that; as far as the `wordsearch` function is concerned, the grid starts totally random and only one word is ever added. Also `random.choice([word])` seems a little unnecessary.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question @Muuuud, i could swear there was this exact question this morning on SO?

Comment: You would have to keep track of words already there and test to see if new word would override existing words. The easiest would be to have no overlaps. If you want to be more fancy you can have words share letters, e.g. ‘e’ from ‘hello’ and ‘red’. This is more complicated as you have to check to see which starting positions and directions are ok. Let me know which you prefer and if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the word positions you are randomly choosing are "colliding" (overlapping) with any of the positions already chosen. If yes, discard that position and generate a new one.

For an example implementation I am representing a word placement with a tuple: `(start_row, start_col, direction, length)`, then the collision could be checked like this:

(this is perhaps a grossly inefficient implementation but should be intuitive; also, for small matrices (<1000 rows) it should work just fine):

```
def get_points(word_placement):
    start_row, start_col, direction, length = word_placement 
    if direction == 'vertical': # column remains same
        return [(start_row+i, start_col) for i in range(length)]

    elif direction == 'horizontal': # row stays  same
        return [(start_row, start_col+i) for i in range(length)]

    elif direction == 'diagonal':
        return [(start_row+i, start_col+i) for i in range(length)]


def do_they_collide (wa, wb):
    points_a = get_points(wa)
    points_b = get_points(wb)
    if len(set(points_a).intersection(set(points_b))) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

## Let's take an example
wa = (0, 1, 'vertical', 5)   # green
wb = (3, 0, 'horizontal', 4) # blue

do_they_collide(wa, wb)
```